# PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE blocks on second thread

Tags: c, pthreads

I have the following problem with the PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE: it blocks when the mutex is locked from another thread;

```
pthread_mutex_t m;
pthread_mutexattr_t ma;

void* exec_th(void* arg) {
    printf("THREAD %p before LOCK\n", pthread_self());

    //second mutex lock
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    printf("THREAD %p after LOCK\n", pthread_self());

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    printf("THREAD %p after UNLOCK\n", pthread_self());

    return (void*)0;
}

int main() {
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&ma);
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&ma, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
    pthread_mutex_init(&m, &ma);

    // first mutex lock
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);

    // create a thread that will call the same mutex
    pthread_t t;
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, exec_th, NULL);

    sleep(1); //just to see the console

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
}
```

The OpenGroup states:

> A thread attempting to relock this mutex without first unlocking it
>   will succeed in locking the mutex. The relocking deadlock which can
>   occur with mutexes of type PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL cannot occur with this
>   type of mutex

Still, the above code generates the same behaviour for PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE and PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL:

- only *before LOCK* is printed before the sleep() in main();
- the thread locks the mutex after it is released by the main();

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it blocks when the mutex is locked from another thread

If the mutex is recursive and the thread that calls `pthread_mutex_lock` already holds that mutex, only then it'll return immediately. In your case, the *main* thread locks the mutex and a different thread attempts to acquire that mutex which gets blocked because it's held by a different. This is normal behaviour.

If *any* thread can unlock any (recursive) mutex held by other thread(s), then recursive mutexes would be useless!

See [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) documentation too.

Comment: makes sense, thank you; also, it seems i've missed the relock keyword in the OpenGroup doc.

Comment: Not-directly-related but recursive mutexes are generally error-prone. See the [commentary by Dave Butenhof](https://groups.google.com/forum/message/raw?msg=comp.programming.threads/tcrTKnfP8HI/me2K7_byNdgJ).

Comment: i was thinking of implementing a retry mechanism with the use of them; retrying while the resource is locked, hm, seemed tempting; most probably will reconsider this; thank you once again.